# How to get XPATH of element in a document with multiple elements with the same id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, xpath

I fetch data from Google's AdWords website which has multiple elements with the same `id`.

I would like to get an XPath of a given element.

Could you suggest a jQuery / JavaScript function that can calculate an XPath of a given element *assuming that the page may contain multiple elements with the same `id`*?

**Please don't tell me that I shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id`. It wasn't my idea...**

Comment: Include a sample with the duplicate `id`s?

Comment: Are you asking us to provide an XPath expression that will get a certain one of these elements? Or are you looking for a JavaScript function that takes in an element and spits out the XPath expression that would select that node?

Comment: @Iwburk: I'm looking for a function that takes an element and returns its XPath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know you can access the the xpath using `//*[@id='blah'][1]` and `[2]` etc.  is that the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I'm just looking for a function that does this.

Comment: I think XPath is one based so `[1]`, `[2]` instead

Comment: Can you explain "Fetch data", in what respect do you "fetch it" in code some way? how is it that you are selecting the element in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the element you want will be the nth occurrence of that id then Martin's suggestion will work.

You can also narrow results by searching by multiple attributes and defining an element, say you know that the id is unique for a div element with a specific name or class.

```
//div[@id='hello' and @name='world']
```

That may be enough for you but if not then you may be able to find the element you want by searching relatively to other elements.

Given the xml:

```
<root>
    <div id='parent1'>
        <div id='element1' />
        <div id='element2' />
    </div>
    <div id='parent2'>
        <div id='element1' name='foo' />
        <div id='element2' name='bar' />
    </div>
</root>
```

You could get the second element 2 in the following ways:

```
/root/div[2]/div[2]
//div[@id='parent2']/div[@id='element2']
//div[@id='element2' and name='bar']
//div[@id='element1' and @name='foo']/../div[@id='element2']
```